# PowerShell File Rename with Padded Zeroes After First Delimeter

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a series of files that I want to rename. I want to rename the files with padded zeroes after the first occurrence of the "-" delimiter like the example below:

**Old Name:** 101-1_File1_Project1-000-END.txt
**Desired New Name:** 101-001_File1_Project1-000-END.txt

I have PowerShell code that almost works, except it applies the padding to all the "-" instances and not just the first one. I've tried a million things and nothing worked. Please help!

PowerShell below:

```
gci "C:\Path\Folder-with-Files" | ren -n {[regex]::replace($_.basename, '\-', {"$args".PadRight(3, '0')})+ $_.extension}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind:

```
gci "C:\Path\Folder-with-Files" | ren -n {[regex]::replace($_.basename, '(?<=^[^-]*)-', {"$args".PadRight(3, '0')})+ $_.extension}
```

The `(?<=^[^-]*)-` regex will match a `-` that is immediately preceded with a start of string (`^`) and then zero or more chars other than a hyphen.

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%5B%5E-%5D*%29-&i=101-1_File1_Project1-000-END.txt).

Comment: Thanks so much - I was fiddling with the look behind and couldn't get it right.

Comment: do you know why {"$args".PadRight(3, '0')}) in this instance doesn't work with file names starting with 101-11 which actually become 101-0011 instead of 101-011 like I would expect?

Comment: @LBro: Your true intent is not to apply _right_-zero-padding to the first `-` instance, but to apply _left_-zero-padding to _the number that follows the first `-`_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68960613/45375) to your follow-up question.